# How can i get last inserted value which is not in the order

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
stock_id-----value

202 --------    212/A1   

202---------    212/A2      

203---------    213/A1

203---------    213/A2  

204---------    214/A1
```

Hi,

In the above result i need to display only 2nd,4th,5th row. Because **212/A2** is the last inserted data for stock_id 202 and **213/A2** is the last inserted data for stock_id 203 and **214/A1** is the last inserted data for `stock_id` 204. How can i get only last inserted rows.

Comment: what is the criteria for last inserted row? Is there any time associated with these rows?

Answer (score 0):

The following could work

```
SELECT stock_id, MAX(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY stock_id
```

Comment: @Febin: if my answer serves your purpose, then you can give accept my answer along with an upvote :) Thanks